# Python Selenium: login facebook with cookies

Tags: python, selenium

I want to login in facebook with a cookie (chrome)

i have a cookie and need login with him.

can somebody write the line to me? thx

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Selenium [documentation](http://from%20selenium%20import%20webdriver%20%20driver%20=%20webdriver.Chrome()%20%20driver.get(%22http://www.example.com%22)%20%20#%20Adds%20the%20cookie%20into%20current%20browser%20context%20driver.add_cookie(%7B%22name%22:%20%22key%22,%20%22value%22:%20%22value%22%7D)), you can add cookies with the following code

> ```py
> from selenium import webdriver
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>
> driver.get("http://www.example.com")
>
> # Adds the cookie into current browser context
> driver.add_cookie({"name": "key", "value": "value"})
> ```

Comment: @JaiminhoCavalcante what is pv?